# Maple Integration of two variables

Tags: variables, integration, convolution, maple

Im trying to find out how to type fig. 1 into maple:

[image: Equation 1]

because when i do it myself i get fig. 2

[image]

This is about forced periodic vibrations.

Comment: Something seems wrong with your integral itself. See for example the top boundary of the integral. It should also have an angular accelaration. Also, is omega_n really a variable?

Comment: no of cause omega_n is not variable.. brain fart :) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are integrating over "Tao" assuming everything else constant for integration. Why don't you redefine a new variable, say y = w*T and let maple evaluate?
If it is just for typing as a text, you can first type in Math format and comment it out with # sign.