# Maple wont evaluate maximum function and only return what I gave him

Tags: maple, maximize

I wrote a function called G and I want to find the maximum and location of that. As the picture showed above it just returned me what I gave him.

Thanks for help!

Here is the code
[image]

Comment: Hi Tong! You should paste relevant code directly in your question.

Comment: Sorry I should have, but I posted it in the link from dropbox. I will post it now

Comment: We still don't see your image. Dropbox link might disappear with time, so your post won't benefit anyone any more. See an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304861/maple-integration-of-two-variables

Comment: Sorry I finally find a way to post it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the future, please **paste** your code into a code block **here** - this way we don't have to rewrite your expressions with possible typing mistakes (or likely: not catching *your* typing mistake, leading to your error).

Comment: Sorry I will try to do that in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your expression does not have an analytic solution - or at least Maple cannot find it with such an ugly expression. You could try the numerical solution

```
Optimization[Maximize](G(nu),nu = 0..0.3);
```

for which I get

> ```
> [1.53103110335302*10^8, [nu = 0.692599771221000e-1]]
> ```

This matches the expected result for when we plot the function:

```
plot(G(nu),nu = 0..0.3);
```

[image: Function to maximize]

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me Error, (in Optimization:-NLPSolve) integration range or variable must be specified in the second argument, got HFloat(1.0) = 0 .. HFloat(0.15)